# Different filters for Palette on Android O notifications

Tags: android

The new Android O notifications for **MediaStyle** will now use the content big picture art and use it for the letters and background of the entire notification.

The end result looks great sometimes, and sometimes it is a bit over the top in regards to color contrast. Since the **Palette API** has filters that allow to configure the behavior (https://developer.android.com/training/material/palette-colors.html), is it possible to set those filters when building a notification with MediaStyle? I know that if I build my own notification with RemoteView I can set those things manually, but that would imply a lot of overhead just for this 1 thing. Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no API for controlling the colorations chosen for `MediaStyle` notifications. Just like all built in styles for notifications, they are templates that manufacturers can customize to their liking (although many stick closely to the AOSP style).

Given that users will be expecting the new style (including the 'bit over the top' colors) and for consistency across all apps, you should continue to use `MediaStyle`.